# How can i associate a static string with an object type C#

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have a method that queries a rest **API** where I do a mapping from **JSON** to an object. Since the query string and object type I pass to this method always have to match I wanted to include the query string as a static string.

```
public class Root
{
    public static string Query;
}

public class RootObject : Root, IRootObject
{
    public D d { get; set; }
    public static new string Query = "AccountSet";
}

public interface IRootObject
{
    D d  { get; }
}

public class RestClass
{
     public void Connect<T>() where T : Root, IRootObject
     {    
        T.Query  <-- fails (not actual code. Just to show my problem)
     }  
}
```

Comment: In C# (or in the CLI in general), the notion of virtual static members does not exist (unfortunately, IMO). Therefore, what you are trying to do cannot work, as `T.Query` (even if it were compileable) would not be polymorphic.

Comment: You can write your own attribute with string parameter to mark your classes. F.e. `[QueryName("AccountSet")] public class RootObject ...`. Then you may use reflection to extract string data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a custom attribute for this:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
public sealed class QueryAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string QueryString { get; private set; }

    public QueryAttribute(string queryString)
    {
        QueryString = queryString;
    }

    public static string GetQueryStringForType(Type type)
    {
        var queryAttr = type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(QueryAttribute), false)
                            .FirstOrDefault() as QueryAttribute;

        return queryAttr != null ? queryAttr.QueryString : null;
    }
}
```

Use it on your classes:

```
[Query("AccountSet")]
public class RootObject : Root, IRootObject
{
    public D d { get; set; }
}
```

And retrieve the value like this:

```
public void Connect<T>() where T : Root, IRootObject
{
    var query = QueryAttribute.GetQueryStringForType(typeof(T));
}
```

Comment: If you abstract the retrieval of the Query attribute into an extension method for `Type`, the code could be quite clean.

Comment: @Baldrick you're right. I refactored this a bit. Having such a method in your toolbox is a good idea.

Comment: @Hmm.. not quite what i had in mind. Does that compile? Not sure it would with `typeof(T)` in the middle of a non generic class...

Comment: @Baldrick oops, I copy/pasted that too quickly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As opposed to languages such as [Delphi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delphi_%28programming_language%29), C# and the .NET CLI in general do not support the concept of static polymorphism.

Therefore, you will require some other way to attach the type-specific information to your types, two of which I suggest here:

1. You can use a [custom attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to mark your class. That attribute can be retrieved from `typeof(T)` with reflection methods such as [`GetCustomAttributes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwc6ew1d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Once you have defined your attribute class, these attributes are quite easy to declare for each type that you want to pass to `T`. The downside is that there is no way to compile-time check whether every class passed to `T` is adorned by such an attribute.
2. Alternatively, you can go for an "info object". Create a base class `ObjectInfo<T>` that serves as a factory for an instance of type `T` *and* as a storage for some metainformation on `T`, for example your `Query` string. For each type that you want to pass to `T`, subclass your `ObjectInfo<T> where T : Root` class (e.g. create a class `RootObjectInfo : ObjectInfo<RootObject>` that overrides the `Query` property of `ObjectInfo<T>` to return the appropriate string). Then, modify `Connect<T>` so it requires an `ObjectInfo<T>` as an argument.